# Ant task not starting the websphere server even there is no error

Tags: java, ant, websphere

I am trying to start the websphere server with ANT Script. when i execute this script it's showing build is successful. But it is not starting the server. Here is the Ant script that i used

```
<target name="initws">
<path id="ibm.lib">
<fileset dir="${env.WAS_HOME}/lib">
<include name="*.jar">
</fileset>

<fileset dir="${env.WAS_HOME}/plugins">
<include name="*.jar">
</fileset>

<fileset dir="${env.WAS_HOME}/java/lib">
<include name="*.jar">
</fileset>
</path>
<taskdef name="wsStartServer"> classpathref="ibm.lib" classname="com.ibm.webphere.ant.tasks.StartServer">
</taskdef>


     <target name="startWebsphereServer" depends="initws">
             <wsStartServer wasHome="${user.install.root}" script="${user.install.root}/bin/setupCmdLine.sh" server="server1" profilename="AppSrv01" failonerror="true"/> 
      </target>
```

Previously i have classpath errors but later i resolved those. when i run this script it is giving the following output and showing that build is successful

```
/*    
    Starting tool with AppSrv01 profile
    Reading Configuration for server : Server1
    Launch Script for server created: /home/dev/IBM/WEBSPHERE/AppServer1/bin/setupCmdLine.sh

    Build Successful
*/
```

but the server is not starting. Can you please help me on this.Thanks in advance for your help. I am doint this in linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

This should be executed from within ws_ant shell that is provided under /bin

Comment: Hi friend thanks for your reply. i tried the solution that you have provided.but it seems there is no difference.  still it is showing build is successful but the server is not started. can you clarify me one thing what is the difference between normal ant and ws_ant command. if i run the ws_ant command from command prompt the server is starting. can we give our build.xml file as input to the ws_ant if yes how can i?  Thanks in advance for your help